# How to fetch ip from a packet using scapy and nfqueue in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy, netfilter

Ok so I have tried already using `packet["IP"].src` but it keeps throwing this error:

> Exception TypeError: "'netfilterqueue.Packet' object has no attribute
>   '**getitem**'" in 'netfilterqueue.global_callback' ignored

using this code in Python line 30: https://hastebin.com/yirahekeju.py

Anyone know why this keeps happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps happening because you're not using it in a right way - **nfqueue.Packet** has a different set of methods and it doesn't support getitem: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/NetfilterQueue

This is how it might work:

```
def check(packet):
    scapy_pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())
    print scapy_pkt.src  # source IP address
    print scapy_pkt.dst  # dest IP address
    # ... work with scapy_pkt
```